# Jaguar S-type (2000) wiper mechanism sometimes very weak

Tags: windshield-wipers, jaguar, s-type

Recently, and not all the time, the wiper arms on my car are so weak that they get stuck on the last wipe of a screen wash 'job'.   At first I thought it was friction with the window, but I've since tested by holding the wipers away from the window with my hands while the arms try to move it. I can feel with my arms holding the wipers that the wiper's arms are struggling to move the whole thing.

Inexplicably - other times they're fine.

I don't quite know whether it's purely mechanical, or relies on the battery, or involves rubber pulleys.   Before I reluctantly take it to a repair garage (where they might quote for an expensive complete system replacement) I thought I might ask here to see if there is any knowledge of how these work in my model of car.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Jags, but it sounds in general like the wiper motor is going out on it.

Comment: I don't know Jags either but it might be the linkage betwen the wiper and the wiper motor. On my vw I had that issue (some time the wiper were fine and some other time they would get stuck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this solution generally, but I'm providing it here as it's what fixed it for me.

I sprayed liberal amounts of WD-40 into the area of the mechanism, and eventually the wipers started to move freely.  They've been fine ever since.

I realize this is a seemingly obvious solution, but I did try WD-40 initially and it didn't work.  It was only after spraying loads of it in frustration (some time later) that the wipers started to move freely.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my 2006 Jaguar S-Type.  It turned out to be the bolt that attached the wiper arm to the chassis was very loose.

Answer (score 1):

Double wiper blades are sometimes the issue.

Comment: In what way? Please elaborate...